# Read a String-object out of a .txt file from the res folder of a Blackberry app

Tags: string, file, text, blackberry

I just started to develop a simple Blackberry app which shows a text sequence in a `RichTextField` on a `MainScreen`. When I define the `String` directly in the sourcecode, then I have no problem to display it. But if I try to read it in from a .txt file which is located in the **res** folder, then I get a `NullPointerException`.

The code below is what I did so far.

```java
package mypackage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import net.rim.device.api.io.IOUtilities;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.RichTextField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;

public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen{
    String str = readFile("Testfile.txt");

    public MyScreen(){
        setTitle("Read Files");
        add(new RichTextField(str));
    }

    public String readFile(String filename){
        InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/"+filename);
        try {
            byte[] filebytes = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(is);
            is.close();
            return new String(filebytes);
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Parts of this code I found in this forum but my problem is that I don't understand when I have to open a connection and when to close it.

And when do I need a Buffer?

And why do I have to convert a `InputStream` to a `byte[]` and then the `byte[]` to a `String`?

All I need is one method, where I can type in the Filename and get back a String-Object with the text which is in my .txt file.

And of course the method should save resources...

Comment: Is the file `Testfile.txt` placed in your project, **directly** in the `res` folder?  And it's spelled exactly that way?  Are you using the BlackBerry Eclipse plugin?

Comment: Yes the file is in the res folder and it's exactly spelled like this. And yes I'm using the BlackBerry Eclipse plugin

Answer (score 0):

```
package mypackage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import net.rim.device.api.io.IOUtilities;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.RichTextField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;

public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen {

public MyScreen() throws IOException {
    setTitle("Read Files");
    add(new RichTextField(readFileToString("Testfile.txt")));
}

public String readFileToString(String path) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/"+path);
    byte[] content = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(is);
    is.close();
    return new String(content);
}
}
```

Yes!!! I found a way to solve my problem.
I don't know why my previous code didn't work but this one works...
The only thing I've changed is that I've added the `throws IOException` instead of surrounding it with a `try - catch` block...